# Cloud run service cannot resolve custom domain mapped to a different cloud run service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am running a Go server on cloud run which makes REST HTTP calls to a different public cloud run service B. When using custom domain mapping for service B, any requests to it error out with the following:

```
Get https://<mydomain_name>/api/health: dial tcp: lookup <mydomain_name> on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
```

However, the requests work when using the automatically allocated cloud run URL instead e.g (https://<myservice_name>-xxxxxxx-ew.a.run.app)

I am able to access the mapped domain name on the browser and I can successfully [dig](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-dig-command-examples) it from my local terminal, from instances on different google cloud projects and from the cloud shell instance. However, querying the domain name servers for the domain name on any instances on the google cloud project hosting service B does not return correct results (fails with NXDOMAIN status).

To me it seems the domain is mapped correctly but I am not sure what is preventing my attempts to access the service using the domain name in code or using curl within the same google cloud project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please check [link1](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4884) & [link2](https://bluecatnetworks.com/blog/what-you-can-learn-from-an-nxdomain-response/) , also check [domain mapping limitations](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#run) &[troubleshoot guide](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/troubleshooting)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya thank you for the link on NXDOMAIN. However, the domain name DNS records are not managed by Google Cloud DNS hence the DNS query should not be going to the metadata server.

Comment: Did u try with domain different name? also check this[link1](https://youtu.be/AgeJhUvEezo),[link2](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq),[link3](https://www.dotcom-monitor.com/wiki/knowledge-base/how-to-troubleshoot-dns-errors/)

Answer (score 1):

NXDOMAIN is the internet’s blunt way of saying “the answer to your question doesn’t exist”. Technically, it’s saying that the domain name referenced in the Domain name System(DNS) query does not exist. NXDOMAIN, which stands for non-existent domain, is an answer that only an authoritative nameserver can return.

If you issue a query for a domain name that does not exist, Google Public DNS always returns an NXDOMAIN record, as per the DNS protocol standards. The browser should show this response as a DNS error.

On the other hand, if the domain name exists, nameservers and DNS resolvers will work to return the positive NOERROR response. The specific IP address answer to the DNS query will be returned as well. (It is also possible to receive a NOERROR response without any specific answers. This happens if the domain exists, but not the DNS record type requested.)

If, instead, you receive any response other than an error message (for example, you are redirected to another page), this could be the result of the following:

- A client-side application such as a browser plug-in is displaying an alternate page for a non-existent domain.
- Some ISPs may intercept and replace all NXDOMAIN responses with responses that lead to their own servers. If you are concerned that your ISP is intercepting Google Public DNS requests or responses, you should contact your ISP.

Comment: Hope this answer helps you to understand why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thank you, it does help but I am still confused since the domain name clearly works from the browser and when queried using dig from any virtual instance and from my local PC. It is the conflicting results as described in my question that stump me